# Prove that $\{\gcd(12n + 3, 7n + 1) : n \in \Bbb Z\} = \{1, 3, 9\}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that $\{\gcd(12n + 3, 7n + 1) \vert\  n \in \Bbb Z\} = \{1, 3, 9\}.$

I just don't know how to proceed with this proof. I have seen a duplicate answer by Bill and Macy here but I am still confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a link to the duplicate answer you've seen, and explain what it is you don't understand about it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123968/prove-that-gcd12n3-7n1n-in-mathbbz-1-3-9

This is the same question asked by another user and it have been marked as duplicate but the duplicate answers use some other method and i am looking for proof by Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: @Syed, have you applied Euclidean algorithm on $12n+3$ and $7n+1$? What did you get?

Comment: I got 1 as the answer

Comment: But what about 9 and 3

Comment: @Syed, it's good to include your work in your question. For example, you didn't even mention that you want to use Euclidean algorithm and it's crucial information. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of the Euclidean algorithm:$$\begin{array}.\gcd(12n+3, 7n+1)&=\gcd(5n+2, 7n+1)\\&=\gcd(5n+2, 2n-1)\\&=\gcd(n+4, 2n-1)\\&=\gcd(n+4, -9)\end{array}$$

You see that the $\gcd$ has to divide $9$, but apart from that there are no constraints since $n$ can be any integer. Therefore the set of possible values is $\{1,3,9\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The extended Euclidean algorithm [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5B12+n+%2B+3,+7+n+%2B+1%5D)
$$
9 = 7(12n+3)-12(7n+1)
$$
Therefore, every common divisor of $12n+3$ and $7n+1$ must divide $9$.